# MongoDB match the most array elements

Tags: mongodb

I have a usecase where I'm not sure if it can be solved with MongoDB in any reasonably efficient way.

The DB contains Consultants, consultants have a set of available weeks (array of week numbers).

I now want to filter on the consultants with the best matching overlap of a given set of weeks.

e.g. consultants:

```
{
    _id: ....
    name: "James",
    weeks: [1,2,3,4,8,9,13]
}

{
    _id: ....
    name: "Anna",
    weeks: [2,3,4,20,23]
}
```

Search data: `[1,2,4]`

The more the overlap, the higher I want to rank the consultant in the search result.

James matches all three entries, 1,2,4. Anna matches 2,4

Is this even possible using Mongo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb : Find common element from two arrays within a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410727/mongodb-find-common-element-from-two-arrays-within-a-query)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate a weight for each consultant as a [setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/index.html) between your search array and `weeks` array:

```
db.consultants.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            weight: {
                $size: { $setIntersection: [ "$weeks", [1,2,4] ] }
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { weight: -1 } }
])
```

The longest the array the more weeks matched so you can $sort by this weight field.